# UWP BLE advertising status is aborted

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

Whenever I start BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher from UWP application its status is aborted. Using same functionality in Console application is without a problem (required libraries are included). When I want to pair with BLE device, I use DeviceWatcher from UWP application without the problem.  OS is Win10, and VS2015 Community is used.

To ilustrate the problem, I made an UWP project with Bluetooth included in capabilities:

```
   <Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />
   <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
   </Capabilities>
```

There are buttons Start, Stop and View, and TextBlock used for displaying status of BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher on MainPage. Code is presented:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher = null;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
            watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;

            textBlock.Text = watcher.Status.ToString();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;

            watcher.Stopped += OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;
        }


        private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            watcher.Stop();
        }

        private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                textBlock.Text = "rcvd" + watcher.Status.ToString();
            });
        }

        private async void OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // Notify the user that the watcher was stopped
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                textBlock.Text = "stopped:" + watcher.Status.ToString();
            });
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            watcher.Start();
            textBlock.Text = watcher.Status.ToString();
        }
        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            watcher.Stop();
            textBlock.Text = watcher.Status.ToString();
        }

        private void buttonView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBlock.Text = watcher.Status.ToString();
        }
    }
```

When the program is started, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher status is Created. After pressing Start button, watcher is started, but status becomes Aborted, and event OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped is triggered (status is still Aborted).

Is there any suggestion for overcoming this problem? Or something that can be additionaly done to clarify the problem?

**UPDATE**

The application is executed on different laptop. The result is the same, therefore it is not the hardware problem.

There are two recommendations on the web:

1. to enable Bluetooth (it is suggested in the first answer by Dmitry)
2. to check capabilities (
   https://keyoti.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-in-windows-10-troubleshooting-capabilities/ )

None provided result.

Additional remark: when event registration for Stopped is removed, 
(// watcher.Stopped += OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;) first result is Started. The next click on button View will display Aborted. For some short fraction of time the result succeeds to be valid.

Any configuration settings suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

This thread helped me.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/5351a1f0-92f3-498b-a0c1-805d568cb55c/when-uwp-ble-advertising-watcher-is-started-its-status-is-aborted?forum=wdk

Solution was to enable "sync with devices" permission (Settings->Privacy->Other devices) for the uwp app.

Comment: This was the solution for my problem. I hope that documentation is updated, because I didn't found anywhere else this recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue than the OP. After `GattServiceProvider.StartAdvertising()` the property `GattServiceProvider.AdvertisementStatus` returns `Aborted`. I tried all of the suggestions above without success.

Next, I downloaded an official Microsoft sample from https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothLE , built and started it and experienced `Aborted` state there as well.

As trivial as it sounds - a simple reboot of my dev laptop fixed the issue. Next time I started the Microsoft sample it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try to enable bluetooth on device while getting status "Aborted".

I've added method LaunchBluetoothSettingsAsync() for this. It's called when OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped have been triggered with status aborted.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher = null;
    private IAsyncOperation<IUICommand> _bluetoothNotOnDialogOperation;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
        watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;

        textBlock.Text = watcher.Status.ToString();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;

        watcher.Stopped += OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped;
    }


    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Stop();
    }

    private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            textBlock.Text = "rcvd" + watcher.Status.ToString();
        });
    }

    private async void OnAdvertisementWatcherStopped(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (watcher .Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Aborted && _bluetoothNotOnDialogOperation == null)
        {
            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(
                "Do you wish to enable Bluetooth on this device?",
                "Failed to start Bluetooth LE advertisement watcher");

            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes",
                async command => { await LaunchBluetoothSettingsAsync(); }));

            messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No",
                command => { watcher.Stop(); }));

            _bluetoothNotOnDialogOperation = messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Start();
        textBlock.Text = watcher.Status.ToString();
    }
    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        watcher.Stop();
        textBlock.Text = watcher.Status.ToString();
    }

    private void buttonView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock.Text = watcher.Status.ToString();
    }

    private async Task LaunchBluetoothSettingsAsync()
    {
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-bluetooth:"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for the effort.

Comment: I have this problem on dell laptop (Bluetooth supported on laptop) used for development . After starting modified app, Bluetooth settings are opened, and I have the info that Bluetooth is started. 

I mentioned that I created class with BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher which is now part of another console application, which is successfully scanning BLE devices (on the same laptop). 

If provided program is working correctly in you environement, then I made a blatant mistake somewhere... or this is a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I also have this same question. How does the software control? I must restart the computer now to solve the problem**

1. My computer can easily reproduce this problem, and quickly turn on/off the system Bluetooth.
2. Then start my program.get watcher status.
   code:

   ```
   BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;
   watcher.Start();
   while (true) {
      BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus status= watcher.Status();
      // std::wcout << status << std::endl;
   }
   ```
3. Output result:

   `Created Stopping Started Aborted Aborted Aborted Aborted ......`

[Here is a reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMQuy.png)